# Best practice to create a node with date for every day in one year with neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need a node for every day with date for a certain year.
Is there a library that i can use for this? I use the neo4j-community version. To create every node manualy cant be the only solution?

Comment: What is the data model for your nodes?

Comment: What's the need for these nodes? It sounds like you need these in order to accomplish some other purpose. If we can understand that purpose, maybe there's another way besides creating a node per day per for the year.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
with 2019 as pYear
with date({year: pYear - 1, month: 12, day: 31}) as startDate, date({year: pYear, month: 12, day: 31}) as endDate
with startDate, duration.indays(startDate, endDate) as daysInYear
with startDate, range(1, daysInYear.days) as daysList
foreach( dayNum in daysList |
   create (:DateNode {date: startDate + duration({days: dayNum})})
)
```

Line 1 sets a local name for the year you want to generate the calenadar for

Line 2 sets local names for the last day of the previous year and the last day of the year of interest

Line 3 then works out how many days there are in the year as a duration. (This is leap year safe.)

Line 4 then creates an integer list of the offset in days from the end of the previous year for any date in the year of interest

The `foreach` in lines 5 to 7 then just iterates over the list and creates a node with property 'date' for each day of the year. The date is created as a temporal type.

You can discard a lot of the 'with'ery in the query, it's just there to show how the query is developed.

You can set up a multi year calendar by setting an arbitary year for the year in `endDate`